# Rspec test belongs_to with shoulda_matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, shoulda

I have this code in my model.

```
belongs_to :user, -> { includes :user_profile }
```

I went through [shoulda doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb) i did not found any way to test that `proc`
containing `includes` part. Please help.

Comment: there is nothing inbuilt AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the model in question is named `Car` (you haven't posted the name of the enclosing class so I'm totally making this up) you can test it as:

```
describe 'user' do
  let(:car) { create_car_somehow }

  it 'preloads the user_profile association' do
    expect(car.user.association(:user_profile)).to be_loaded
  end
end
```

`#association` returns metadata of the specified association (of type `ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation` and so on). The returned object responds to `#loaded?` which returns `true` if the association has been loaded and `false` otherwise.

Comment: where is `be_loaded` defined? Can you post a link to the docs?

Comment: It's a dynamic [predicate matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-2/docs/matchers/predicate-matchers) defined on the fly. Basically, `expect(object).to be_foo` is automatically converted to `expect(object.foo?).to be_truthy`.